# How to get timezone.today as default value?

Tags: django, datefield

I would like to set my DateField's default value to today's date in UTC timezone.

If I put `datetime.now(timezone.utc).date()`, it will be a fixed value that is called when the server restarts.

If I put `timezone.now`, it will return datetime object, not day object.

How can I get the today's date in UTC timezone? A function that is callable (without parentheses at the end)
Because if I put `timezone.now().date`, won't it be called when the server is restarted only, not every time the object is created/updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mostly solved your own problem. Simple create "a function that is callable".

```
from datetime import datetime

def today_utc():
    return datetime.utcnow().date()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.DateField(default=today_utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file you must set this var:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Now in your code if you want to get the correct utc now date you do so:

```
from django.utils import timezone

today = timezone.now().date()
```

If you have field in your model is `DateField`, example: `my_field` do so:

```
my_field = models.DateFiel(default=date.today)
```

If you have field called `my_field` set `DateTimeField` do so:

```
my_field = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield)